# Puling a specific item from a foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I have a project with 2 tables(Categories and products). They have One to Many relationship. Many products have one Category. Am pulling products of a specific category(together with its price and description) and storing in one variable so that I can use in the view. In the view am having a foreach loop whereby I want to display each row from the products table of a specific category(a product with its price and description) but it fails,,please assist?

FrontController

```
public function itemOne() {
    //Get all phones(Have category of 1 ) in categories table
    $mobile = Category::find(1)
        ->products()
        ->whereNotNull("image")
        ->whereNotNull("name")
        ->whereNotNull("description")
        ->whereNotNull("price")
        ->whereNotNull("category_id")->get();

    return view('front.products')->withItems($mobile);
}
```

Products.blade.php

```
@foreach($items as $item)
                <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$item->image) }}">
    <br> {{  $item->name}} <br> {{ $item->price }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting please provide that.

Comment: @amitrawat No error occurs, all first items are displaying only,but I want each item in the foreach loop to display differently from the previous one together with its specific price and description?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function itemOne() {
    //Get all phones(Have category of 1 ) in categories table
    $mobile = Category::find(1)
        ->products()
        ->whereNotNull("image")
        ->whereNotNull("name")
        ->whereNotNull("description")
        ->whereNotNull("price")
        ->whereNotNull("category_id")->get();

    return view('front.products',compact('items'));
}
```

use compact in return

Comment: ,,, Hello I have rectified but the problem persist,,,a single item in the foreach loop is being repeated constantly,,, but I need each item to display uniquely without being repeated together with its price and description..